# How to add provison Profile Certificate in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, udid, xcode8.2

I have added 2 new  devices with their UDID in apple developer website and downloaded the  Mobile provision profile Certificate with extension(.mobileProvision).Now I need to add this in XCODE 8 so that when i host my app in Diawi.com so the URL will work in the devices which I have added.But I am not able to drag or import or install it.PLease tell me how will it work.

Comment: Are you able to select the latest certificate in 'Build Settings'?

Answer (score 1):

Just double click on Mobile provision profile Certificate with extension(.mobileProvision) file. It will install automatically. After that close your XCode and reopen it. Then you can select that provision profile Certificate under **Signing** in  **Build Settings.** Or in General tab **Signing** select your team and click on **Automatically manage signing**. it will start working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) First install the certificates both for development and distribution.

2) Then install your development and adhoc provisioning profile you created.

3) Now switch to Xcode and select **target** **project** and then select **General** tab. Here turn off the automatically manage signing.
   If everything is right with certificates and provisioning profiles, then your provisioning profile should be listed in drop down list when you set profiles for debug and release.

[image: As shown in this image]